# Изменение ключей объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты

Имеется объект menu, нужно заменить в нем ключи на новые с верхним регистром. Функция выводит в консоле их, но не заменяет их в существующем объекте.

```
var menu = {
    burger : 300,
    friedpotato : 40,
    pizza : "out of stock"

}

function touppercase(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        prop = prop.toUpperCase();
        console.log(prop); // выводит верхний регистр
    }
 
}
touppercase(menu);
console.log(menu);
```

Делал похожий пример, где заменял значение ключей. Там все сработало :

```
var menu = {
    burger : 300,
    friedpotato : 40,
    pizza : "out of stock"

}

function newmenu(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] == "number") {
            obj[prop] *= 2;
        }
        if (typeof obj[prop] == "string") {
            obj[prop] = "in stock";
        }
    }
}

newmenu(menu);
console.log(menu); //{ burger: 600, friedpotato: 80, pizza: 'in stock' }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так в первом примере?

Дополнение :
А как быть тогда в таком случае? Чтобы тоже заменяло name на верхний регистр

```
var workers = [
    {
        name : 'maxim',
        lastname : 'ivanov'
    },
    {
        name : 'ivan',
        lastname: 'borisov'
    }
];

function namestoupper(...args) {
    for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
        if (typeof args[i].name == "string") {
            var upped = args[i].name.toUpperCase();
            console.log(upped);
        }
    }
}

namestoupper(...workers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

надо так менять ключи

```
function touppercase(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if(typeof prop === 'string'){
          obj[prop.toUpperCase()] = obj[prop];
          delete obj[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

prop.toUpperCase() возвращает новую строку, которая у вас идет в консоль, а не в объект

```
function namestoupper(...args) {
    for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
        if (typeof args[i].name == "string") {
            args[i].name=args[i].name.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете посмотреть Дополнение, как сделать тогда в таком случае?

Comment: добавил в ответе

Comment: вот теперь все стало на свои места, благодарю